# New log line starts with single quote

Tags: java, layout, formatting, log4j

I have the following appender layout:

```
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MM/dd/yyy HH:mm:ss} level='%-5p' node='%X{node}' channel='statistic' thread='%t' \
  message='%m%n '
```

in console I see following:

```
03/31/16 14:38:49 level='INFO ' node='' channel='statistic'  thread='Scanner-2' message='Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
 '03/31/16 14:38:50 level='DEBUG' node='' channel='statistic'  thread='Scanner-2' message='Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
 '03/31/16 14:38:50 level='DEBUG' node='' channel='statistic'  thread='Scanner-2' message='Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
....
```

I want to avoid that new line starts with single quote. this quote should be placed on previous line.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: remove single quote from last means after message='%m%n ' remove this single quote from last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the message pattern to **%m%n**, or perhaps **'%m'%n** if you really want the single quotes

Answer (score 2):

The message format is using a new line appender but after that are you appending the single quoute...
use instead:

```
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MM/dd/yyy HH:mm:ss} level='%-5p' node='%X{node}' channel='statistic' thread='%t' \
  message='%m'%n
```